# Updating database using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update my database tinyint to 1 when the checkbox is checked and to 0 when the checkbox is unchecked. My Javascript/Ajax code is:

```
<script>
function emailNextWithAddress(chk,address) {
    var nextEmail, inside_where;
    if(chk.checked === true){
        $.ajax({
            url: "marca_enviado.php",
            type: "get",
            data: address,
            success: function(){
                nextEmail = document.createElement('input');
                nextEmail.id = address;
                nextEmail.value = address;
                nextEmail.type = 'text';
                nextEmail.name = 'email[]';
                nextEmail.className = 'insemail';
                nextEmail.style.display = 'inline-block';
                inside_where = document.getElementById('addEmail');
                inside_where.appendChild(nextEmail);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Erro!");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "desmarca_enviado.php",
            type: "get",
            data: address,
            success: function(){
                inside_where = document.getElementById(address);
                inside_where.parentNode.removeChild(inside_where);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Erro!");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

And the php (marca_enviado.php) code which tries to update my database tinyint is:

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $address = $_GET['address'];

    $updateEnviado = "UPDATE escolas SET Enviado = 1 WHERE id= 'address' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn , $updateEnviado);
 ?>
```

Comment: What is the error you got when run this code???

Comment: @LakmalAbesekara No error, it just doesn't update the database.

Comment: `$updateEnviado = "UPDATE escolas SET Enviado = 1 WHERE id= 'address' "` There are multiple things wrong here, you are always updating to 1 and you are always updating a record having `id= 'address'` which probably does not exist

Comment: @Herco I have one php file to update to 1 and one php file to update to 0. Doesn't the id= 'address' come from the Ajax data: address ?

Comment: in `data: address,` what is `address`?

Comment: @TheUnknown You may want to use the same PHP file to toggle 0 and 1, copying code WILL get you into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: @TheUnknown id= 'address' will always look for field id having value 'address'. This needs to be a variable, but you need to look out for sql injection. Google for "mysqli prepared statements".

Comment: Share what is `address` or sample of this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $address = $_GET['address'];

    //-- escape the input data. But be sure to add some validations before this line.
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $address);    

    //-- use "$address" variable there, assuming that variable contains the id
    $updateEnviado = "UPDATE escolas SET Enviado = 1 WHERE id= '$address' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn , $updateEnviado);
 ?>
```

Hope it helps!